# Given graph of a function $f(x)$, find area under $f(x^2-1)$ from $-1$ to $1$

Tags: integration, graphing-functions, area

Source: MAT $2011$
[image]

Above is the graph of the function $f(x)$. It is required to find
$$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x^2-1)dx$$
So the function $f(x)$ can be split into two parts -

1. $f(x) = \left(x+1\right)$ for $-1 \le x \le 0$
2. $f(x) = \left(-x+1\right)$ for $0 \lt x \le 1$

Their transformations would be the following respectively:

1. $f(x^2-1) = x^2$ for $-1 \le x \le 0$
2. $f(x^2-1) = -x^2 + 2$ for $0 \lt x \le 1$

So I should be able to integrate both of these functions in their respective domains to get my answer.
$$\int_{-1}^{1}{f(x^2-1)dx} = \int_{-1}^{0}{(x^2)dx} + \int_{0}^{1}{(-x^2+2)dx} = 2$$

Yeah, my method is completely wrong. How should I do it, and why is my method wrong?

Comment: You could start with the observation that$$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x^2-1)dx =2\int_{0}^{1}f(x^2-1)dx.$$ Then perhaps you can introduce $t=x^2-1$.

Comment: Your method fails because you do not apply the transformation properly: $f(x^2-1)=x^2 $ for $-1 \le x^2-1 \le 0$ and so forth

Comment: @Gary I am not sure how to proceed after what you wrote

Comment: @acelixis Well, $$
\int_{ - 1}^0 {\frac{{f(t)}}{{2\sqrt {1 + t} }}{\rm d}t}  = \int_{ - 1}^0 {\frac{{1 + t}}{{2\sqrt {1 + t} }}{\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{2}\int_{ - 1}^0 {\sqrt {1 + t} \,{\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method fails, because you don't change the domain of your piece-wise defined function. Take, for example, $x=0.5$. Therefore, $x^2-1 = -0.75$, meaning: A point thay used to lie on the right side is now on the left side. The domains (especially the borders of those) must be altered to suit this transformation.
E.g.: The first part of your domain should actually be $-1 \leq x^2-1 \leq 0$. Do you see the problem with your integral?

I would figure out the new domains for the two parts of the function. For the first part that would be $-1 \leq x^2 -1 \leq 0$, therefore $0 \leq x^2 \leq 1$ and for the second part $0 \lt x^2 -1 \leq 1$, therefore $1 \lt x^2 \leq 2$. Meaning: you have now new inequalities defining your domains. Figure out, for which x each of the inequalities is fulfilled (that is: solve the inequalities for $x$) and you obtain the new final domains for your tranformed function (hint: It will be more than two pieces). Finally, you can integrate between -1 and 1 knowing which function will reside where.